# Array calculations work through iteration but don't "stick" after moving to sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a very large set of data, 2 columns and 25k+ rows, that I pull into an array.  I then calculate those two values, dump into another array and paste the answer array to a range of cells.  Everything is working great, except when I get a specific set of values that seem to calculate correctly (as I step through the array calculations) but after the array dumps back to the sheet, the wrong answer persists!

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Code:

```
Dim lCt As Long
    lCt = FUNCS.CountMyRows("NSI", "A:A")

'Build array to hold data
        Dim arrData, arrAnswers As Variant
        arrData = Range("C2:D" & lCt)

        ReDim arrAnswers(1 To lCt - 1, 3)

        'Loop through the rows of the array doing calcs and pasting the value to the sheet
        Dim i As Long
        Dim iA As Integer
        iA = -1
        Dim a1, a2 As Double
        For i = 1 To lCt - 1
            'Assign data to variables for readability of formulas
                a1 = arrData(i, 1)
                a2 = arrData(i, 2)

            'Build answers for NSI 1 Day
                If a2 = 0 Then
                    arrAnswers(i, 0) = 1
                ElseIf a1 = 0 Then
                    arrAnswers(i, 0) = 1
                Else
                    arrAnswers(i, 0) = ((a2 - a1) / a1) * -1
                End If
            'Last formulas
                If a2 >= (a1 * 2) Then
                    arrAnswers(i, 1) = -1
                Else
                    arrAnswers(i, 1) = arrAnswers(i, 0)
                End If
        Next i

        'Spit out the array data that was calculated
        Worksheets("NSI").Range("E2:E" & lCt).Value = arrAnswers

        'empty the arrays
        Erase arrData
        Erase arrAnswers
```

Data Example - you can see there should never be -2000%, it should only allow up to -100%, but there they are!

[image: Data Example]

Comment: You are using a 2D array, in your `arr(i, 0)` you calculate: `((466.6 - 16.2) / 16.2) * - 1` which equals: `27.80246913580247‬`. So your results are correct, when you dump back your data you are only dumping on column E, which will show the `(i, 0)` dimension, your `(i, 1)`dimension won't paste unless you expand your range to column `F`.

Comment: Fixed... oh my god I'm embarrassed with how long I've been messing around with this.  UGH!  Thank you!